# Install WinXP/7/8 on Android Device

Tags: windows, emulators, sony-xperia-z1

I know that it's possible to install WinXP or other Windows versions to an Android device, but I don't know how.

I tried BOCHS but it doesn't work on my Xperia Z1 or I don't know how to set it up correctly.

Is there some complete tutorial or something?

**Remark:** I don't want to *replace* Android on the device. I want to run Windows "on top of it" (e.g. in a VM).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Running Windows in a PC emulator on your phone is almost certainly not the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use a [QEMU based app like the one from MotionCoding](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.motioncoding.emulator), but I can't see it running on anything other than very high end Android devices.  Even then, I doubt a VM will work very well...